# Access to global variables when importing a custom class

Tags: python

I have the following structure in my project:

```
    myProject
    |- classes
       |- myclass.py
    |- main.py
```

But `myclass.py` doesn't see variables defined at `main.py`

main.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from classes.myclass import myclass
outputPath = '/some/path/'
classInst = myClass()
```

myclass.py:

```
import pandas as pd

class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        global outputPath
        self.outputPath = outputPath
        dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Is it possible to define global variables in `outputPath` in `main.py` *only* and use in that in all classes?

Comment: You can access `outputPath` from `myclass.py` via `import main; print(main.outputPath)`.

Comment: Any reason not to pass output_path as a parameter at class init? `classInst = myClass(output_path='/some/path/')`?

Comment: If you want to avoid circular import issues (main import classes, classes import main), you may add a third file imported where needed. E.g. params.py, containing that `output_path` declaration.

Comment: @Jérôme: There are many such parameters I would like to have them as a config somewhere and not to send them to each class instance.

Comment: Please stick to a *single* question per post. `import` in Python is a form of *binding*, you are adding names for objects you need in that module. If you need access to Pandas in `myclass` then you must import *something* that gives you access to the Pandas module. There is little point in making your code harder to follow by trying to avoid using `import pandas`.